# how to install library in pyCharm?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pycharm

i am new to python(2.7) and i am using pyCharm 4.0.6 community on Ubuntu 14.04 and i am working in a school project and i am supposed to use numpy library so whenever i try to install numpy it gives me that error "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

and here is a screenshot of [the error](http://postimg.org/image/ub9ky555h/full/)

and i have tried to use virtual environment but it yields [this error](http://postimg.org/image/9wnamj6nh/)

Comment: `Col1     Col2  Expected`

`0   7.645   5.2119      46.0`

`1   7.079   3.4145      28.7`

`2  91.900  24.0000      50.0`

`3   5.875   1.1296      50.0`

`4   6.153   3.2797      29.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `sudo apt-get install python-dev` to install the python header files.

Comment: now i am trying to install matplotlib and i got this [error](http://postimg.org/image/bketnhux9/)

do you have any idea why ?

Comment: i do not know i am installing from the pyCharm itself not from terminal , how can i know

Comment: try installing from bash

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev`